# How to make responsive Google Map in Zurb Foundation

Tags: google-maps, zurb-foundation

I have try use zurb foundation 3. But have some problem with google maps. While I use google maps, the columns didn't want to be responsive.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="six columns">short description</div>
<div class="six columns"><iframe>GOOGLE MAPS CODE</iframe></div>
</div>
```

Anyone could help me, please.

Thank you

Comment: In Zurb f6 - use responsive embed:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-embed.html

Answer (score 9):

try wrapping it in

```
<div class="flex-video"> </div>
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/flex-video.html

> If you're embedding a video from YouTube, Vimeo, or another site that uses iframe, embed or >object elements, you can wrap your video in div.flex-video ## Heading ##to create an intrinsic ratio that >will properly scale your video on any device.

Comment: This solution also works well when used without iframes

Answer (score 4):

I used google maps with Zurb Foundation and it was working for me. and I did not use iframes.

```
<div id="map_canvas" class="six columns" style="height: 800px"></div>

<div class="six columns" style="height: 800px"></div>
```

Comment: but it didn't work for me, the size is same not responsive. Can I look your website that use your above method? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enclose the map into an element with id `map_canvas`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="six columns">short description</div>
    <div class="six columns">
        <div id="map_canvas" ><iframe>GOOGLE MAPS CODE</iframe></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's built-in in F3. If you go and check in `foundation.css` you will find that class in a few places.

Comment: yeaps, I found the code [#map_canvas embed { max-width: none; }] but your suggestion didn't work. ???

Comment: I have a site where I use that technique I gave you. Unfortunately I can't link to it here and show it to you as it will violate the rules here. (will look like I'm advertising). I tried putting it in jsfiddle but google map won't load there. I'll check tomorrow if it's possible, and how, to load Google map in jsfiddle so I can show you that it works - and how you can make it work in the process. Cheers for now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is often that the percentage doesn't work, when I corrected from

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 40%;"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The "Flex Video" class so far is the best way to do this although it adds a major padding to the bottom of a div. So it's six of one half a dozen the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just add style="max-width:100%;" to your iframe code. As long as the iframe is inside of one of Foundation's columns, it will scale to fit. Note that this has been tested with Foundation 3, not 4 or 5. It should, however, work for those as well.